# Linq - Get results bigger capacity then current

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have following a table called Resources where it has couple of capacity fields ; `CapM3`, `CapUD` and `CapMT`.

I would like to **get list of resources where capacity is equal or larger than a default supplied resource**.

```
public static IList<Resources> GetSwapResources(string resourceID)
    {
        //selected resource
        var res = db.Resources.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ResourceID == resourceID);


        //select all active resources excluding selected
        var resources = db.Resources.Where(p => p.Active == true && p.ResourceID != resourceID);
        //not sure how to filter here

        return resources.ToList();
    }
}
```

I think I will be able to do this by looping for desired results. But, can that be handled within LINQ query itself?

Comment: Just put it in the `Where` condition like everything else? I'm not understanding what you're not understanding...

Comment: How come filtering `db.Resources` will return `IList<ResourceSwap>`?

Comment: @RahulSingh, it was incomplete code. I asked the question while was still figuring out the logic.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I will be able to do this by looping for desired results. But,
>   can that be handled within LINQ query itself?

Yes, you can chain as many conditions to the Where clause as you wish:

```
var res = db.Resources
    .Where(p => p.ResourceID == resourceID)
    .Where(p => p.Active == true)
    .Where(p => p.CapM3 >= 1234)
    .Where(p => p.CapM3 >= 5678);
```

Or if you wanted to use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
var res = db.Resources
    .Where(p => p.ResourceID == resourceID)
    .Where(p => p.Active == true)
    .Where(p => p.CapM3 >= 1234 || p.CapM3 >= 5678);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out on how to achieve desired result :

```
    public static IList<Resources> GetSwapResources(string resourceID)
    {
        //selected resource
        var res = db.Resources.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ResourceID == resourceID);


        //select all active resources excluding selected
        var resources = db.Resources.Where(p => p.Active == true && p.ResourceID != resourceID);
 .Where(a => a.CapM3 <= res.CapM3 && a.CapMT <= res.CapMT && a.CapUD<= res.CapUD);            

        return resources.ToList();
    }
}
```